# Definition of wave maps

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

The general definition for a wave equation is

$\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 x}-\dfrac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 t}=0$  (or $=f$)

for some $u \in C^{2}([0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^N)$.

Now, I also read the definition that a linear wave equation is of the form:

$g^{\mu \nu}  \partial_{\mu} \partial_{\nu} u+ a^{\mu} \partial_{\mu}u +bu =0$

where $g^{\mu \nu}$ are components of a smooth  $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix valued function, $g^{00} < 0$, $g^{ij}$ positive definite, $a^{\mu},b$ smooth $N \times N$ matrix valued functions.

Well, it's not unusual, that there are different definitions for something also also it's clear, that the second definition is a generalization of the first. Still, I'm wondering how common the second definition for a wave map is, since I didn't see it anywhere except some specific sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When thinking about a wave on any non trivial geometry the second definition would apply. A vibrating circular membrane is one physical example where the second definition applies. In that case it has the form

$$\left(-\partial_t^2 + \partial_r^2+\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_\theta^2+\frac{1}{r}\partial_r\right)u(t,r,\theta)=0$$

Where $u$ represents the lateral elevation. In this case $[g^{\mu\nu}]=\text{Diag}(-1,1,\frac{1}{r^2})$and $[a^\mu]=(0,\frac{1}{r},0)$. In general, on a pseudo-Riemannian manifold with a metric of signature $(-1,1,...,1)$ a Levi-Civita connection one can write a "wave equation" as

\begin{align}
g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_u\nabla_\nu u &=-k^2u\\
g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\partial_\nu u - \Gamma^\mu\partial_\mu u &=-k^2u
\end{align}

Where $\Gamma^\mu=g^{\lambda\nu}{\Gamma^\mu}_{\lambda\nu}$ and the gammas are the Christoffel symbols.

Comment: If I understand you right, you're saying that the second definition is more likely to be seen as a definition for wave maps on manifolds which are not sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: No, just on any Riemannian manifold, it could be a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^m$. The point I was trying to make is that if the space has a non trivial metric you would have to use the second definition, the first definition applies to waves in a flat space in Cartesian coordinates which is very specific.